# Generate a raster with a uniform value using QGis

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-modeler

I'm working on a project using the qgis-modeler and I want to generate a raster with a uniform value.

I'm using r.surf.random function of GRASS which needs min and max values but I want to have only one input.

So how can I generate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GRASS:

```
r.mapcalc "uniform_raster = 1"
```

(or any other value you choose)
As always with GRASS, be sure to *set the region first.*